# Highly Recommended References for the Theory of Modular Forms for Normal Subgroups of Finite Index of $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, modular-group

I am looking for a highly recommended reference for the **Theory of Modular Forms for Normal Subgroups of Finite Index of $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$**.

Many references, that have been mentioned before on this website, discuss the Theory of Modular Forms for $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ and Congruence Subgroup of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ (**I don't need them at all**).

All I need is a reference to understand this part of the article, starting from "1.2. Modular Forms...".
Where $G=PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see any reason to restrict to normal subgroups. $\Gamma_0(N);\Gamma_1(N)$ have Hecke operators whose eigenforms have multiplicative Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @reuns since I need to understand this part of the article. The other references didn't help me out at all to be honest.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of reference you are looking for. Maybe what you need isn't a reference, but an exercise: Use the Riemann--Hurwitz genus formula to compute the genus of the modular curves you are interested in. This way you will also see one reason why normal subgroups are convenient. That being said, reuns is right: you won't really see that much simplification in the key ideas of the theory by restricting to normal subgroups.

Comment: That being said, I think you could answer a lot of your questions by reading Diamond-Shurman (if you want something very detailed) or Ch. 1 of Silverman's advanced topics book on elliptic curves (there you will learn how level 1 works and you can treat it as an exercise, as above, to extend the arguments to the subgroups you are interested in).

Comment: @babu_babu you mean chapter 1 of ((Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves))

Comment: @Neilhawking yes, that's the one.